# How to add commas in between JSON objects using Linux Shell and SnowSQL?

Tags: json, linux, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

While there are several posts about this topic on Stack Overflow, none match my exact use case. I am using a Linux shell script to run SnowSQL to generate a json file.

========================

My json file needs to have a comma between json objects.

This:

```
{
  "CAMPAIGN": "Welcome_New",
  "UUID": "fe881781-bdc2-41b2-95f2-e0e8c19dc597"
}
{
  "CAMPAIGN": "Welcome_Existing",
  "UUID": "77a41c02-beb9-48bf-ada4-b2074c1a78cb"
}
```

...needs to look this:

```
{
  "CAMPAIGN": "Welcome_New",
  "UUID": "fe881781-bdc2-41b2-95f2-e0e8c19dc597"
},
{
  "CAMPAIGN": "Welcome_Existing",
  "UUID": "77a41c02-beb9-48bf-ada4-b2074c1a78cb"
}
```

Here is my complete ksh script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

. /appl/.snf_logon
export SNOW_PKEY_FILE=$(mktemp ./pkey-XXXXXX)
trap "rm -f ${SNOW_PKEY_FILE}" EXIT
LibGetSnowCred

{
    
outFile=JSON_FILE_TYPE_TEST.json
inDir=/testing
outFileNm=@my_db.my_schema.my_file_stage/${outFile}


snowsql \
    --private-key-path $SNOW_PKEY_FILE \
    -o exit_on_error=true \
    -o friendly=false \
    -o timing=false \
    -o log_level=ERROR \
    -o echo=true <<!

COPY INTO ${outFileNm}

FROM (SELECT object_construct(
'UUID',UUID
,'CAMPAIGN',CAMPAIGN)
FROM my_db.my_schema.JSON_Test_Table
LIMIT 2)

FILE_FORMAT=(
TYPE=JSON
COMPRESSION=NONE                                                                                             
)
OVERWRITE=True
HEADER=False
SINGLE=True
MAX_FILE_SIZE=4900000000
;


get ${outFileNm} file://${inDir}/;
rm ${outFileNm};

!

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Export successful"
else
    echo "ERROR in export"
fi

}
```

Is the best practice to add the comma during the SELECT or after the file is generated and how?

Comment: Use `ARRAY_AGG()` to aggregate all the results into a single array.

Comment: Thanks, Barmar. Can you provide sample sql for that?

Comment: _"My json file needs to have a comma between json objects."_ -- there is no such thing as a "JSON object" or "JSON array". [JSON](https://json.org) is a text representation of a data structure (that can be an object, an array or a scalar). In order to manipulate the data, the JSON needs to be parsed, to get back data structures similar to those used to create the JSON. With or without that comma, the text is just some random text that looks like JSON but is not JSON. A JSON must to be valid to be decoded. Do not generate JSON by string concatenation! Use a function provided by the language.

Comment: None of the texts that you posted in the question is JSON. They look like JSON but they are not. The comma does not make much difference. In order to be JSON it needs comma between objects and everything wrapped in `[` and `]`. That would be an array of objects encoded as JSON.

Comment: The current code encodes each row as JSON. If it is possible, tell the code to represent each such JSON on a single row (compact). That is a valid file format named [JSON lines](https://jsonlines.org). It is not standard but there are many tools that can handle it. [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq`) is one of them. It can be used to combine all these objects into an array, to produce a valid JSON that contains all the data.

Comment: Or maybe you can tell the database to generate a JSON that contains all the rows (an array of objects), not individual JSONs for each row.

Comment: @axiac The JSON specification calls the text enclosed in `{}` an object ("An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs."), and `[]` an array. Why do you say there's no such thing as a JSON object? Your nitpick is normally only appropriate when calling the in-memory data a JSON object, but here we're talking about the text.

Answer (score 0):

With or without that comma, the text is still not JSON but just a random text that looks like JSON. You export several rows, each row as an independent object. You need to gather all these objects into an array to produce a valid JSON.

A JSON that encodes an array of rows looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "CAMPAIGN": "Welcome_New",
    "UUID": "fe881781-bdc2-41b2-95f2-e0e8c19dc597"
  },
  {
    "CAMPAIGN": "Welcome_Existing",
    "UUID": "77a41c02-beb9-48bf-ada4-b2074c1a78cb"
  }
]
```

The easiest way to produce this output would be to ask the database, if it supports this option (to wrap all the records into a list before generating the JSON, to not export each record in a separate JSON).

If this is not possible then you have a file that contains multiple JSONs. You can use [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq) to convert these individual JSONs into a JSON similar to the one described above (encoding an array of objects).

It is as simple as that:

```bash
jq --slurp '.' input_file > output_file
```

The option `--slurp` tells `jq` to read all the JSONs from the file `input_file` in memory, to parse them and to put them into an array. That is the program input.

`'.'` is the `jq` program. It says *"dump the current object"*. It does not do any processing to the input data. The current object is the array.

After it executes the program (which, in this case doesn't do anything), `jq` dumps the modified value (as JSON, of course) to the standard output (by default, on screen).

The `> output_file` part redirects this output to a file (named `output_file`) instead of showing it on screen.

You can see [how it works](https://jqplay.org/s/-XuOkEtIUpj) on the `jq` playground.